# How to get Line of code for a project in Sonar

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I am developing an application in which i display some details of each project in Sonar. So i want to show the line of codes for each project in my page. I have access to Sonar DB. Can anyone tell me the tables / queries that i should use to get the line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: **do not** try to get the data from the database directly. It's not an API, data structures may change anytime in there, at the discretion of technical implementations.

You're safe though: SonarQube exposes all its data/workflows via [its Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) . Go through its documentation and you'll find *api/measures/component* ([documentation](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/measures/component)): *Return component with specified measures.*

Real-life example:

- this project on sonarqube.com (51k LOC as of writing). Key (shown on right pane) is *org.apache.abdera:abdera* .
- querying *api/measures/component*:

  > https://sonarqube.com/api/measures/component?componentKey=org.apache.abdera:abdera&metricKeys=ncloc

Gives you the value for that *ncloc* metric. Job is done. :)

Note: same approach works for any metric (see [Metric Definitions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Metric+Definitions) for info on metric keys).

Comment: thank you very much !!!! I want to get other details like BUGS VULNERABILITIES CODE SMELLS AND LAST ANALYSIS also. Could you please help me with query to get all these?

Comment: Like I said: use the same approach with other metric keys (list in [Metric Definitions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Metric+Definitions)). For example: use `metricKeys=ncloc,bugs,vulnerabilities,code_smells` . It's up to you now, play and experiment with the Web API, lots of stuff you can do there.